# JDBC connecting to SQL Server 2005 - Connection Refused

Tags: sql-server-2005, jdbc

I create a JDBC connection to SQL Server 2005. It throws the error Connection Refused.

> java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect

I already enable TCP/IP in SQL Configuration Manager and the port 1433 but it's still impossible to connect.

[image: JDBC Connection Properties]

Answer (score 0):

Run this query on the target DB and then try to connect again
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yourusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword'`

Comment: Granting `ALL PRIVILEGES ON <everything>` doesn't look the best of ideas.